# Ruby: Convert ARGV to a string

Tags: ruby

**Question**: Is there a simple way to print out an array in Ruby with elements separated by spaces?

**Details**:

I want to use Ruby to Benchmark commands and run the command.  Something like:

```
 script.rb ./command_name arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

For example:

```
 script.rb ls -lh
```

should run `ls -lh`.  I tried to do this with:

```
require 'benchmark'
puts Benchmark.measure{system(ARGV.to_s)}
```

(note ignore benchmark for this question I just included that because that what I'm using this for) but that does not work because ARGV gets printed without spaces.  For example `ls -lh` becomes `ls-lh`.  Obviously I could create my own string by parsing the ARGV array and inserting spaces between elements in loop.  But I assume there is a more elegant Ruby solution but I haven't been able to figure one out yet so I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Update]

You should use [l0b0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55153164/62082)

[Original answer]

You can easily join elements of an Array together [with `join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join). ARGV is an Array.

```
ARGV.join(" ")
```

Comment: if you expect spaces in any of the args, you need to escape them: `require 'shellwords'` then `escaped_args = ARGV.map{|arg| Shellwords.escape arg}.join ' '`

Answer (score 4):

To produce a reusable argument string:

```
ARGV.map{|arg| Shellwords.escape arg}.join(' ')
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine and should be marked as accepted. Don't forget to `require 'shellwords'`.

Comment: To note, you can also use `Shellwords.shelljoin(ARGV)` or (once you `require 'shellwords'`) `ARGV.shelljoin`

Comment: I used this in a Vagrantfile and didn't have to `require` anything. Don't know if that carries over to regular Ruby, though.